# Redirect the user when the user visits the particular route in Ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, routes, ionic4

I am working in my Ionic 4 App and I am working on Login system and When the user will login, it will redirect to the page where the user can check the challenges for the user and when the user is not login and if it try to visit the page then it should redirect to the other page.

This is my **userlogin.ts**:

```
async UserLoginDetails($soctype, $socid) {
    const loading = await this.loadingController.create({
      message: 'Please Wait',
      duration: 1100,
      translucent: true,
    });
    await loading.present();
    const userdetailslogin = {
      email: this.userlogindet.value.email,
      password: this.userlogindet.value.password,
      social_type: $soctype,
      social_id: $socid,
    };
    this.chakapi.loginUser(userdetailslogin, 'userLogin').subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      if (data) {
        this.responseEdit = data;
        if (this.responseEdit.status === 'success') {
          console.log(this.responseEdit.data.id);
          this.storage.set('ID', this.responseEdit.data.id);
          this.presentAlertConfirm('Login Successful', 1);
        } else {
          this.presentAlertConfirm('Either You are not registered Or not approved user.', 0);
        }
      }
    });
    return await loading.onDidDismiss();
}

async presentAlertConfirm($messge, $para) {
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      message: $messge,
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          role: 'cancel',
          cssClass: 'secondary',
          handler: () => {
            // console.log('Confirm Cancel: blah');
            if ($para === 1) {
              this.modalController.dismiss();
              this.router.navigate(['/tabs/tab2']);
            }
          }
        }]
    });
    await alert.present();
}
```

When the user will login, its user Id will get store in the storage.

This is my **tabs.router.module.ts**:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { TabsPage } from './tabs.page';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'tab1',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: '../tab1/tab1.module#Tab1PageModule'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'tab2',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: '../tab2/tab2.module#Tab2PageModule'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'tab4',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: '../login/login.module#LoginPageModule'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'tab3',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: '../tab3/tab3.module#Tab3PageModule'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/tabs/tab1',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/tabs/tab1',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class TabsPageRoutingModule {}
```

I want that when the user is not login and it will try to visit the `tab2` route, it should redirect to some other page.

Should I use the guard service or I am doing this correctly. I am storing the User Id in the storage because I want to use it multiple times.

Any suggestion or help is much appreciated. Please help me with the code because I am working on a project and I want to complete it on time.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a guard to accomplish this.  The guard will determine if the user is logged in or not. If not, the user will be redirected to another route (login page or wherever you want them to land).

---

#### authentication.guard.ts

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthenticationGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private _router: Router) {}

  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {

    let isLoggedIn: boolean = false;

    // NOTE: Do your logic here to determine if the user is logged in or not.

    // return true if use is authenticated
    if(isLoggedIn) return true;

    // else redirect the user to another route and return false.
    this._router.navigate(['login']);
    return false;
  }
}
```

#### tabs.router.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      ...
      {
        path: 'tab2',
        canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard],
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: '../tab2/tab2.module#Tab2PageModule'
          }
        ]
      },
      ...
    ]
  }
  ...
];
```

---

Angular guards are used like filters.  You can add an array of guards/filters to your route which all must be satisfied in order to access that route (acts as a chain).  In your routing array add a `canActivate` attribute to the route you want filtered.  In the above example I added the `AuthenticationGuard` to the `tab2` route which will only run when the user tries to access `tab2` or any of it's children.  You can place `canActivate` at the root of the routes (`tabs`) to filter all children of `tabs` route (will filter `tab1`, `tab2`, etc).

> https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate
>
> https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: I am storing the User ID in the storage. Can you please help me with the code in authentication.guard.ts. If the storage exists, the route will open otherwise the user will redirect to some other route.

Comment: @Rahul , In the guard you would simply pull the user from storage by the key you set it.  If it's not `null` or `undefined` return `true` .  You could say something like `if(this.storage.get('user')) return true`.  If `this.storage` is referring to a service you will have to inject the service in the constructor of the guard.

Comment: What if I define the id in the path: 'tab2/:id'.

Comment: I'm not sure I undestand your question.  If `tab2/:id` is a child route of `tab2` and you have the guard placed on `tab2`, navigating to `tab2:id` will require the guard to pass.

Comment: tab2/:id will open when the id exists and if the id doesnt exists, it will redirect to some other route.

Comment: if you put a path for `:id` as  child path of `tab2`, the `canActivate` on `tab2` will be applied to all children.  If you need another specific guard, you can create another guard and apply it to the child route in the same manner.